# Calculate $\nabla (\mathbf i\wedge\mathbf r)$

Tags: calculus

I was working out a tutorial and the question was like this.  "Consider **r** = x**i** + y**j** + z**k**, work out $\nabla (\mathbf i \wedge \mathbf r)$."  I am not sure what value should I take for $\mathbf i$.  According to the answer it should be equal to -**i**.

Comment: what is the meaning of (1^r)? Cross product?

Comment: it is the cross product of i^r not 1^r

Comment: Actually, you’ll have to tell *us* what $\mathbf i$ and the other symbols mean. Based on the supposed answer, $\nabla$ is not the usual vector calculus gradient operator since the gradient of a vector is a rank-two tensor. I suspect that $\wedge$ is not really the usual cross product, either. On the other hand, if $\mathbf i$ and friends are meant to be the basis vectors and $\wedge$ and $\nabla$ have their usual geometric algebra/calculus meanings, then the answer is missing a factor of $2$. Surely there are definitions earlier in the tutorial for all of these symbols—share them with us.

Comment: @user7075815 Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

We have

$$\vec i \times \vec r=\begin{vmatrix}\vec i&\vec j&\vec k\\1&0&0\\x&y&z\end{vmatrix}=-z\vec j+y \vec k$$

Comment: The gradient of that would be equal to (0,-1,1) right?

Comment: @user7075815 usually the gradient is on a scalar field, here we are calculating the gradient of a vector which is  a matrix, refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1565075/505767

Comment: In this context, $\nabla$ isn’t the ordinary gradient operator of vector calculus. You’re being asked to find the differential of a bivector.